# web scraping is not working using google api

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

The issue is that the code below is returning null. The goal is to pick up data (dollar amount of the minimum wage) from a specific website using google api.

for the code its using regex to look for the match but the match is always returning null.

```
function getMinimumWage() {
  // Specify the URL
  var url = "https://www.epi.org/minimum-wage-tracker/#/min_wage/Washington";

  // Fetch the HTML content of the page
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var htmlContent = response.getContentText();

  // Use regular expressions to extract the dollar amount before the next </div> following the phrase "Minimum wage"
  var regex = /Minimum wage.*?<p[^>]*class="main"[^>]*>\s*([$0-9.]+)\s*<\/p>.*?<\/div>/s;
  var match = htmlContent.match(regex);

  // Check if a match is found
  if (match && match.length > 1) {
    var minimumWage = match[1];
    Logger.log("Minimum Wage in Washington: " + minimumWage);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Minimum wage not found on the page.");
  }
}
```

I even tried searching the simple text below and tried displaying but the result is null

```
var regex = /Most recent increase/; 
var match = htmlContent.match(regex);
Logger.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: Is `UrlFetchApp.fetch` a promise? The code doesn't seem to wait for it to finish fetching nor does it pass a callback for it to run.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i tried displaying the context by running Logger.log(htmlContent); it does have texts in it but its says its truncated because the result is too large. but it should still hold all the HTML contents right? the logger is only the one that is limited.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, UrlFetchApp.fetch is not a promise; it is a synchronous function in Google Apps Script. The script execution will wait for the UrlFetchApp.fetch request to complete before moving on to the next line of code.

Comment: The content you are looking for does not appear to be contained in that initial HTML the browser receives when requesting that URL; looks like it gets loaded and inserted into the document via JavaScript. I doubt that what you are currently using there, behaves like an actual browser, and executes JavaScript and makes further requests, if necessary ...?

Comment: What value do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @Tanaike when you go to the website, its the Washington minimum wage dollar value, which is $16.28. Its located in the upper right part of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> when you go to the website, its the Washington minimum wage dollar value, which is $16.28. Its located in the upper right part of the site.

I understood that you wanted to retrieve a value of `$16.28` from the URL of `https://www.epi.org/minimum-wage-tracker/#/min_wage/Washington`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function getMinimumWage() {
  var stateName = "Washington"; // Please set your state name.

  var url = "https://www.epi.org/minimum-wage-tracker/#/min_wage";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = res.getContentText();
  var tr = [...text.matchAll(/<tr>[\w\s\S]*?<\/tr>/g)].find(e => {
    var temp = e[0].match(/<th scope="row">(.*)<\/th>/);
    return temp && (temp[1].trim() == stateName);
  });
  if (tr) {
    var minimumWage = tr[0].match(/\$[\d.]*/);
    if (minimumWage) {
      Logger.log("Minimum Wage in Washington: " + minimumWage[0]);
      return;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Minimum wage not found on the page.");
}
```

- When this script is run, `Minimum Wage in Washington: $16.28` is shown in the log. For example, when `var stateName = "Washington D.C.";` is used, `Minimum Wage in Washington: $17.00` is shown in the log.

#### References:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: i just edited the regex to get the number without the $ sign

Comment: if (tr) {
    var minimumWage = tr[0].match(/<td>\s*\$([0-9.]+)\s*<\/td>/); 
    if (minimumWage) {
      Logger.log("Minimum Wage in " + stateName + ": " + minimumWage[1]);
      return Number(minimumWage[1]);
    }
  }

Comment: my other question is that. so UrlFetchApp.fetch wasn't really the issue here. correct?

Comment: @Chadd Dum Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `i just edited the regex to get the number without the $ sign`, in this case, how about modifying `Logger.log("Minimum Wage in Washington: " + minimumWage[0]);` to `Logger.log("Minimum Wage in Washington: " + minimumWage[0].replace("$","").trim());`?